# "List not found" when appending to a list using a loop and function

Tags: r

Objective: Apply a function over each iteration of a loop and take the results of each iteration and append to a list (global variable) that I can use after the function has run.

```
myBigList <- list()
doStuffList <- function(i, the_list) {
    a <- runif(10)
    b <- rnorm(16)
    c <- rbinom(8, 5, i/10)
    name <- paste('item:',i,sep='')
    tmp <- list(uniform=a, normal=b, binomial=c)
    the_list[[i]] <- tmp
}

for(i in 1:5) {
  doStuffList(i, myBigList)
}
```

This code runs, but after running the variable MyBigList is empty. I tried changing `the_list[[i]] <- tmp` to `the_list[[i]] <<- tmp` however this gave me an error:

```
"Error in the_list[[i]] <<- tmp : object 'the_list' not found"
```

How can I pass the global variable list to the function and add to it during each iteration? Outcome would be a list with 5 components.

Comment: Try to add `return(tmp)` in the end of your function and add `print(doStuffList(i, myBigList))` in your loop.

Comment: @Miha The `return()` wound't change anything as the assignment in the last line of the function is already returning `tmp` (just doing so silently) and the `print()` would just print five different lists of one element, it won't make a list with five elements. I really don't see how that would work. Maybe you could turn it into a full answer so we could run it and see.

Comment: @MrFlick you are right, my mistake. Thanks for the note. But he could get the desired output just by creating a empty list before the loop for example `d <- list()` and then assign his function to list within a loop like this `d[[i]] <- doStuffList(i, myBigList)`. The result `d` is a list with five elements like in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify a variable you pass to a function, it will only be modified inside that function scope, not where it came from. Functions should return updated values. Here's a more R-like way to do the same thing here using `lapply()` rather than a `for` loop.

```
doStuffList <- function(i) {
    a <- runif(10)
    b <- rnorm(16)
    c <- rbinom(8, 5, i/10)
    name <- paste('item:',i,sep='')
    tmp <- list(uniform=a, normal=b, binomial=c)
    tmp
}
myBigList <- lapply(1:5, doStuffList)
```